# posting data in $http post request

Tags: angularjs, http

I'm trying to post data from my form to an API on another domain. Request body comes back empty.
When I go to devtools, payload shows as [object Object]

I tried setting different headers like 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' or undefined but had no luck

**CODE**

$scope.form

```
{
   "name":"Test",
   "email":"test@test.com",
   "companyName":"company",
   "companySize":"6 - 10 employees",
   "manageTimeOff":true
}
```

submit function

```
$scope.submitForm = function () {
    $scope.success = false;
    $scope.loading = true;

    $http({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: $scope.form,
        withCredentials: false,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.loading = false;

        if (response.data.Error) {
            $scope.success = false;
            swal("Something's gone wrong ☹", response.data.Error, "error")
        } else {
            $scope.success = true;
            swal({
                title: "Form Submitted",
                text: "We look forward to speaking with you soon!",
                icon: "success"
            });

            $scope.resetForm();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please shows us the log of $scope.form

Comment: Content type `x-www-form-urlencoded` is obsolete. Design backends to use content type `application/json` which the AngularJS framework supports by default.

Comment: Sorry, should've made it more clear in my question, $scope.form is the object above submitForm()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content type `x-www-form-urlencoded` is obsolete. Design backends to use content type `application/json` which the AngularJS framework supports by default.

```
$http({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    data: $scope.form,
    withCredentials: false,
    ̶h̶e̶a̶d̶e̶r̶s̶:̶ ̶{̶ ̶"̶C̶o̶n̶t̶e̶n̶t̶-̶T̶y̶p̶e̶"̶:̶ ̶"̶a̶p̶p̶l̶i̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶/̶x̶-̶w̶w̶w̶-̶f̶o̶r̶m̶-̶u̶r̶l̶e̶n̶c̶o̶d̶e̶d̶"̶ ̶}̶,̶
    ̶t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶f̶o̶r̶m̶R̶e̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶:̶ ̶a̶n̶g̶u̶l̶a̶r̶.̶i̶d̶e̶n̶t̶i̶t̶y̶
}).then(function (response) {
    //...
});
```

Comment: This helped, thank you. I'm now getting cors error but I guess this is a step forward ¯\_(ツ)_/¯